# The following packages have been kept back

Tags: held-packages

Here is a long list of packages that have been kept back:

```
The following packages have been kept back:   aptdaemon
fcitx-frontend-qt5 gir1.2-packagekitglib-1.0 kde-style-breeze    
kde-style-breeze-qt4 libfcitx-qt5-1 libkf5archive5 libkf5auth-data    
libkf5auth5 libkf5codecs-data libkf5codecs5 libkf5config-data    
libkf5configcore5 libkf5configgui5 libkf5configwidgets-data    
libkf5configwidgets5 libkf5coreaddons-data libkf5coreaddons5    
libkf5guiaddons5 libkf5i18n-data libkf5i18n5 libkf5iconthemes-data    
libkf5iconthemes5 libkf5itemviews-data libkf5itemviews5 libkf5style5    
libkf5widgetsaddons-data libkf5widgetsaddons5 libkf5windowsystem-data 
libkf5windowsystem5 libqt4-dbus libqt4-dbus:i386 libqt4-declarative    
libqt4-declarative:i386 libqt4-designer libqt4-network
libqt4-network:i386   libqt4-opengl libqt4-opengl:i386
libqt4-qt3support libqt4-script   libqt4-script:i386 libqt4-sql
libqt4-sql:i386 libqt4-sql-mysql:i386   libqt4-sql-sqlite libqt4-svg
libqt4-xml libqt4-xml:i386 libqt4-xmlpatterns    
libqt4-xmlpatterns:i386 libqt5core5a libqt5dbus5 libqt5gui5    
libqt5multimedia5 libqt5network5 libqt5opengl5 libqt5positioning5    
libqt5printsupport5 libqt5qml5 libqt5quick5 libqt5quicktest5
libqt5script5   libqt5sql5 libqt5sql5-mysql libqt5sql5-sqlite
libqt5svg5 libqt5test5   libqt5webkit5 libqt5widgets5 libqt5x11extras5
libqt5xml5 libqtcore4   libqtcore4:i386 libqtdbus4 libqtdbus4:i386
libqtgui4 libqtgui4:i386   python-aptdaemon
python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets python3-aptdaemon    
python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets qdbus qml-module-qt-labs-folderlistmodel
qml-module-qt-labs-settings qml-module-qtgraphicaleffects    
qml-module-qtquick-layouts qml-module-qtquick-window2
qml-module-qtquick2   qml-module-qttest qml-module-qtwebkit qmlscene
qtchooser   qtdeclarative5-dev-tools 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 
to remove and 94 not upgraded.
```

I've tried to run this shell script that I made to remove broken packages, but i could not remove any at all:

```
grep Broken /var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log | cut -d\   -f2 | while read -r package ; do
    echo "Processing $package"
    sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq $package
    sudo apt-get update
done
```

Answer (score 4):

Solved it!

```
sudo apt full-upgrade && sudo apt autoremove
```

Comment: Note: sometimes "kept back" is shown for a package in a phased update. See https://askubuntu.com/a/1421232/2273 and https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StableReleaseUpdates#Phasing . Try running `apt-cache policy PACKAGENAME` and look for the word `phased`.

Comment: I am running `sudo apt upgrade -y ; sudo apt full-upgrade -y ; sudo apt autoremove -y ; sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y` and even all this is not enough to resolve the issue. Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/216371/apt-get-dist-upgrade-doesnt-fix-the-following-packages-have-been-kept-back