# Ubuntu won't upgrade on dist-upgrade

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates

I try to look around and didn't find a fair answer.

`sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` run well.

The problem is when I try to run `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` it just doesn't execute to upgrade

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  python3-distupgrade ubuntu-release-upgrader-core ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded
```

Do I miss something?
Any words of wisdom?

Comment: A more specific answer to this exact question (same four packages): https://askubuntu.com/a/1421232/19626

Comment: Got it. Didn't think of looking for that kind of Q and A.
thank you. Will check if this repeat on next dist-upgrade

Comment: When the Phased Updates are complete, the packages will install with an ordinary `upgrade`. `full-upgrade` nor `dist-upgrade` won't be necessary. All that you need to do is be patient.

Comment: @user535733 full-upgrade also didn't help. Manual add select pack resolve it =)

Comment: In other words, you worked around Phased Upgrades. That was unwise: See https://people.canonical.com/%7Eubuntu-archive/phased-updates.html. At least one of those packages reported errors, and their distribution has been paused for troubleshooting. By defeating Phased Upgrades, you may have created new problems for yourself by force-installing a buggy package.

Comment: @user535733 oh I see. Well, hope all will be ok. If they troubleshoot it, will there be an update/upgrade when they fix the reason for troubleshooting?

Comment: Read https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StableReleaseUpdates and https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/phased-updates-in-apt-in-21-04/20345 for the answer to your follow-up question.