# Error processing .dev archive since update. It's preventing other packages from updating as well

Tags: 22.04, deb, archive

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/desktop-file-utils_0.26-1ubuntu3_amd64.deb
 
The following packages have been kept back:
cryptsetup cryptsetup-bin cryptsetup-initramfs cryptsetup-run python3-software-properties
software-properties-common software-properties-qt
The following packages will be upgraded:
desktop-file-utils
```

Now those packages are stuck because of this error.

I tried removing, redownloading, force-overwriting the .deb, and I also tried all of these but they don't work:

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/desktop-file-utils_0.26-1ubuntu3_amd64.deb

apt install -f; sudo apt-get upgrade; sudo apt-get --with-new-pkgs upgrade; sudo apt-get dist-upgrade;
```

What's wrong with this update and what can I do about it?

Comment: As the error is pointing to the cache, have you tried a `sudo apt clean` to rebuild the cache? 

Comment: You are correct: You have a cache issue, but that's not why those particular packages are not updating. See [Update/Upgrade not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1421222/update-upgrade-not-working)