# "The following packages have been kept back" with no obvious reason

Tags: apt, package-management

During routine maintenance I noticed some packages "have been kept back":

```
The following packages have been kept back:
  gnome-control-center-data isc-dhcp-client isc-dhcp-common
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
```

I have read ["The following packages have been kept back:" Why and how do I solve it?](/q/601/612877) but the reasons given there weren't satisfactory. `apt-mark showhold` produces empty output.

Previously I have seen this message (packages kept back) when upgrading `curl` which changed dependency from `libcurl3` to `libcurl4`. But this time, taking `gnome-control-center-data` as an example, there's no change in dependency packages:

```
$ apt list gnome-control-center-data -a
Listing... Done
gnome-control-center-data/jammy-updates 1:41.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.4 all [upgradable from: 1:41.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.1]
gnome-control-center-data/now 1:41.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 all [installed,upgradable to: 1:41.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.4]
gnome-control-center-data/jammy-security 1:41.4-1ubuntu13.2 all
gnome-control-center-data/jammy 1:41.4-1ubuntu12 all

$ apt show gnome-control-center-data=1:41.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
...
Depends: dconf-gsettings-backend | gsettings-backend
Breaks: gnome-control-center (<< 1:3.7.92-2~)
Replaces: gnome-control-center (<< 1:3.7.92-2~)
...

$ apt show gnome-control-center-data=1:41.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.4
...
Depends: dconf-gsettings-backend | gsettings-backend
Breaks: gnome-control-center (<< 1:3.7.92-2~)
Replaces: gnome-control-center (<< 1:3.7.92-2~)
...
```

I know I can force an upgrade by specifying the packages on the command line (so I'm not in need of a quick solution). But this has occurred multiple times recently, each time involving distinct packages. I would like to know the reason (cause) behind this.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the complete output of `apt-cache policy <packagename>` for each of those three packages.

Comment: Then see [Update/Upgrade not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1421222/update-upgrade-not-working). The `apt-cache policy` output will show you that those three packages are currently in Phased Updates. The link will explain Phased Updates and what you should do about it.