# 14 Jammy Security Updates will not upgrade when running 'sudo apt upgrade'

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, thinkpad

Running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on ThinkPad X1 Extreme Gen2

When I run

```
sudo apt update
apt list --upgradable
sudo apt upgrade
```

14 Jammy updates are found.
After running `sudo apt upgrade` it install 0/14 available upgrades.
I am relatively new to Ubuntu and installed 22.04 LTS as a DualBoot on my Thinkpad.
Output I am getting
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Update/Upgrade not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1421222/update-upgrade-not-working)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's pick a random package from that list, and check `apt policy` upon it:

```
$ apt policy libitm1
libitm1:
  Installed: 12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04
  Candidate: 12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04
  Version table:
 *** 12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04 500 (phased 20%)
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     12-20220319-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
```

Look at the Version Table lines:

See the `(phased 20%)`?

That means the particular package is in the process of Phased Updates.

**Your system is not broken. There is nothing wrong**

- Phased Updates is one precaution to prevent everybody from receiving a buggy package via upgrade: Some people get the upgraded a few days earlier, others a few days later. This provides an opportunity to pause distribution if early folks report problems.
- Do not try to force the upgrades. Apt will properly install each upgraded package automatically when your turn comes. Phasing typically runs a week or so. Simply run apt update and apt upgrade again in a few days.

**Simply be patient. Apt will install those packages in a few days.**

Comment: +1 great analysis. Wouldn't it have been nice if a message had been added saying "the following packages are waiting to be installed due to phased updates" instead of using the same message that many of us have been associating for years with problems in the package system.

Comment: Thank you so much @user535733! I am enjoying using Ubuntu, and learning.

Comment: I have the same for packages: gcc-10-base gcc-10-base:i386, but apt policy does not show any phasing process.  Rather it provides the following useful information: 500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 Packages. What action would you take in this case?