# I can't get system updates to install

Tags: updates

I've tried both through Software *and* sudo apt-get update / sudo apt-get upgrade (**"The following packages have been kept back:
grub-common grub-pc grub-pc-bin grub2-common
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded."**)

Xubuntu 22.04

[image]

Comment: They would eventually be rolled out as phased upgrades https://askubuntu.com/q/1421222/124466

Comment: Let's hope it's that , then.